# increase the Max number of element in an excel vba array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need some advice on the below as I cannot enter anymore elements as I need to include quite a lot of field. Any possible way to keep on adding after "yy" ? Thanks

```
Dim v As Variant, x As Variant, findfield As Variant
Dim oCell As Range
Dim iNum As Long
v = Array("project Name", "Path", "xx","yy"......)
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: i'm using this in a excel

Comment: I suggest you read [the docs on declaring arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays).

Also please check out [how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) next time you post a question.

Comment: Or you use a [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)